# How to add several dataframes to each other and find the number of rows that are repeats?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, counting

I have a several pandas dataframes that look like this. For this example, here are 3 of them:

```
    Sequence  Group
    SGF       1
    AVQ       2
    SGQ       3
    AIT       4

    Sequence  Group
    SGF       1
    AVQ       2
    AAI       3
    CBT       4

    Sequence  Group
    SGF       1
    AVQ       2
    SGQ       3
    AIE       4
```

Is there a way to add all the data frames together and then for each sequence count how many times a sequence shows up in the set?

Expected Output:

```
    Sequence   Group    Number of Times
    SGF        1        3
    AVQ        2        3
    SGQ        3        2
    AAI        3        1
    AIT        4        1
    AIE        4        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `pd.concat` and `groupby`:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).groupby(['Sequence','Group'])\
                        .agg({'Sequence':'size'})\
                        .rename(columns={'Sequence':'Number of Times'})\
                        .reset_index()\
                        .sort_values(by=['Number of Times','Group'], ascending=[False,True])
```

Output:

```
  Sequence  Group  Number of Times
5      SGF      1                3
3      AVQ      2                3
6      SGQ      3                2
0      AAI      3                1
1      AIE      4                1
2      AIT      4                1
4      CBT      4                1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've your dataframes as list, use `pd.concat` and groupby on `['Sequence', 'Group']` and get count using `size`

```
In [398]: pd.concat([d1, d2, d3]).groupby(['Sequence', 'Group']).size()
Out[398]:
Sequence  Group
AAI       3        1
AIE       4        1
AIT       4        1
AVQ       2        3
CBT       4        1
SGF       1        3
SGQ       3        2
dtype: int64
```

To sort them order use `sort_values`

```
In [399]: (pd.concat([d1, d2, d3]).groupby(['Sequence', 'Group']).size()
             .reset_index(name='Times')
             .sort_values(by=['Times', 'Group'], ascending=[False, True]))
Out[399]:
  Sequence  Group  Times
5      SGF      1      3
3      AVQ      2      3
6      SGQ      3      2
0      AAI      3      1
1      AIE      4      1
2      AIT      4      1
4      CBT      4      1
```